# unable to return the result from a method in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, mongodb-query

i am trying to fetch the result from the database using a function but it is showing that undefined but when i am printing the result in the same method it is  printing .. i got to know the reason that node js executing in async but i dont know how to over come this issue

```
var mongo=require('../routes/mongo')

exports.search=function(userid){
    // console.log(userid)

    mongo.get().collection("customers").find({"userid":userid}).toArray(function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;

        // console.log(result)

        return result;


    });


}
```

when i am printing this in some other module it is printing undefined

it tried to print using this `console.log(dboperations.search(req.body.userid))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because doing database operations is async you can't get the result as sync. You could use a callback.

```
var mongo=require('../routes/mongo')

exports.search=function(userid, callback){
    // console.log(userid)

    mongo.get().collection("customers").find({"userid":userid}).toArray(function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;

        // console.log(result)

        callback(result)
    });
}
```

And then call the function like

```
dboperations.search('id of the user', function (result) {
    console.log(result)
})
```

A nice article about async programming https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Comment: thanks its working but its fetching all the records in the database but i need only the record that i send as a parameter i.e.userid

Comment: @vamsireddy sec i'll fix

Comment: thanks man its working